# Can I use Serilog.Extra.Web's HttpRequestNumber or HttpRequestId as the SerilogMetrics timed-operation identifier?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, metrics, serilog

I'm using SerilogMetrics's `BeginTimedOperation()` in a Web API, and it would be really great to be able to use the `HttpRequestNumber` or `HttpRequestId` properties (from the respective Serilog.Extra.Web enrichers) as the identifier, making it super easy to correlate timing-related log entries with others across a request.

Something like:

```
using (logger.BeginTimedOperation("doing some work", HttpRequestNumberEnricher.CurrentRequestNumber))
{ ... }
```

Short of poking around in `HttpContext.Current` for the magically- (i.e. non-public) named properties, is this achievable? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you begin a timed operation during a web request, the operation's events will already be tagged with the `HttpRequestId`.

You'll see it when logging to a structured log server like Seq, but if you're writing it out to a text file or trace then the property won't be included in the output message by default. To show it in there use something like:

```
.WriteTo.File(...,
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp} [{Level}] ({HttpRequestId}) {Message} ...")
```

The logging methods use a default template you can draw on for inspiration, and there's some info spread around the [wiki](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Configuration-Basics#enrichers) though there's no definitive reference.